# Get number of <li> in any <ul> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code in which I need to find the number of `li` tags, not the nested ones.

```
<ul class="ulStart">
   <li>
      <ul class="ulNested">
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Doing

```
document.querySelector('.ulStart').getElementsByTagName('li')
```

Gives me 4 `<li>`, which is not what I want, I want the number of `li` tags present in `ulStart`. Let me know if there is any way to do so. No jQuery, pure javascript.

Comment: You may use `document.querySelector('.ulStart').children.length`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let count = document.querySelectorAll("ul.ulStart > li").length;
console.log(count);
```

```html
<ul class="ulStart">
  <li>
    <ul class="ulNested">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Use the `>` (direct child) CSS selector. See [MDN - Child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.ulStart > li').length);
```

```html
<ul class="ulStart">
   <li>
      <ul class="ulNested">
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="ulStart">
   <li>
      <ul class="ulNested">
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Try use the following query selector:

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.ulStart > li').length);
```

Results in:

```
HTMLCollection(2) [li, li]
```